# How do I fix JRebel config in Eclipse after accidentally removing JRebel nature?

Tags: java, eclipse, jrebel

While trying to fix an unrelated error in my Eclipse java project, I accidentally clicked the context menu item "JRebel -> Remove JRebel Nature". I then re-enabled it by clicking "JRebel -> Add JRebel Nature". But now JRebel isn't working and this icon is displaying in the Eclipse Project Explorer next to my rebel.xml file. What's going on here? How do I go about diagnosing the error and fixing it?

[image: rebel.xml error]

Comment: Have you tried re-generating the rebel.xml in the project settings?

Comment: @MalteHartwig Yes, and it re-generated the file, but it didn't seem to have any effect. It still shows the error icon and doesn't hotswap my code.

Comment: Have you checked that the source folder you want to be hotswapped is mentioned in the xml? Maybe the path is incorrect. I remember that I had to correct the path sometimes when copying and switching workspaces.

Comment: The red X is probably coming from your SCM integration.